# Set input value with local storage?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, local-storage

EDIT: Issue was fixed, I surrounded it in a document ready function

On my first page i'm saving data via local storage, this is saving correctly.

```
localStorage.setItem("firstname", "David");
```

On my second page I want to show this data into an input field, it works when I display this info in a h1 element but I can get it to show in input

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("firstname");
```

My input:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name"  required="required"/>
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 5):

As this is input type so `innerHTML` will not work here just try to replace `innerHTML` with `value`

replace

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
```

with

```
document.getElementById("name").value = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
```

or with jQuery you can do this:-

```
$('#name').val(localStorage.getItem("firstname"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies i'm completely lost, I tried your example it didn't work. I've moved the script to the bottom too and still no luck

Comment: check your browser console if there any other error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: localStorage.setItem("firstname", "David");
    document.getElementById("name").value = localStorage.getItem("firstname");

Comment: it means there is no element available with id `name`. did you wrap your script under `$(document).ready(`?